# PHP WebDAV Server Certificate Failed

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, webdav

Currently setting up a backup solution that sends a database dump and some other files from a Wordpress network to a NAS on my LAN, via WebDAV. I have installed PHP WebDAV on my web server and the basic code to get that that to work is:

```
webdav_connect('http://webdav.example.com/dav', 'davuser', 'davpassword');
webdav_put('/your/nice/thing.txt', $data);
webdav_close();
```

The issue is, my NAS requires this connection to be done via HTTPS, so in a web browser you'd see a warning which you can ignore, but PHP gives the following warning and the code fails:

> **Warning:** webdav_put() [function.webdav-put]: Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted in **/var/www/vhosts/blah/blah/blah.php** on line 5

Is there a way in which I can ask PHP to ignore this, or will I need to obtain an SSL certificate? The domain name used for accessing the WebDAV service on my NAS is one provided by Dynamic DNS if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness as I don't like leaving things un-answered. I've decided to access my WebDAV service via SMEStorage. They provide an API which developers can use for this sort of thing:

http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=for_developers

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in which I can ask PHP to ignore this, or will I need to obtain an SSL certificate?

I don't know which HTTP Layer PHP WebDAV uses (which extension are you using?), but often it's possible to configure the underlying layer to ignore certificate errors.

If you need certificate verification for security reasons, you should obtain a valid certificate.

Comment: PHP WebDAV uses the Neon library as far as I can tell - there's very little documentation on it - http://php-webdav.pureftpd.org/project/php-webdav

Comment: Hmm, I don't know that library. You could dig through the source-code if there are any configuration settings available you can change with your php.ini / `ini_set`. Or look for an alternative WebDAV PHP library that offers such a feature/setting.